# What is the correct way to access Genius API via AJAX without receiving http 403 on preflight request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, http, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a very small google chrome extension to open the [Genius](https://genius.com/) lyrics page for the song I'm listening on Spotify. I managed to correctly get the song data from Spotify, and I can authenticate the user to Genius, but when I search for the song, the request fails on preflight.

Genius is responding with `{"meta":{"status":403,"message":"Action forbidden for current scope"}}`, and chrome is printing this on the console: `Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403`.

Even though Genius appears to blame the token's scope, I tried authenticating with all scopes (`me`, `create_annotation`, `manage_annotation`, and `vote`) and the issue persists. Also, the same request works fine with Postman using the same token.

My code is as follows:

```
let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("GET", "https://api.genius.com/search?q=Paranoid", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
xhttp.send();
```

The full request:

```
General
Request URL:https://api.genius.com/search?q=Paranoid
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:403 
Remote Address:104.16.213.100:443
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Request Headers
:authority:api.genius.com
:method:OPTIONS
:path:/search?q=Paranoid
:scheme:https
accept:*/*
accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, br
accept-language:pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
access-control-request-headers:authorization
access-control-request-method:GET
origin:chrome-extension://ppkhnbipegikhcenmfgpajgphcdkgdej
user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36

Response Headers
access-control-allow-headers:Origin, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Content-Type, Accept, X-Auth-Token, Authorization
access-control-allow-methods:GET, PUT, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE
access-control-allow-origin:*
cache-control:no-cache
cf-ray:3e3dc4d51f888138-GRU
content-encoding:gzip
content-type:application/json; charset=utf-8
date:Sat, 27 Jan 2018 18:27:56 GMT
expect-ct:max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
server:cloudflare
set-cookie:__cfduid=db59a3c93b09d3f7b0907ed395ceb1b341517077676; expires=Sun, 27-Jan-19 18:27:56 GMT; path=/; domain=.genius.com; HttpOnly
status:403
status:403 Forbidden
via:1.1 vegur
x-runtime:11
```

Genius API, for reference: https://docs.genius.com/

Answer (score 5):

I was doing something similar with React and was getting the same error, as I found no answer online, the only thing that worked for me was: instead of doing a request to the url and sending headers for authentication separately (as it is recommended in the documentation) what worked was sending the access_token as a query_string (without sending headers) like: 
`https://api.genius.com/search?q=Paranoid&access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN`